# @ExceptionHandler method not going to view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

I am trying to use @ExceptionHandler in my controller to handle an exception I created purposely in my DAO by giving the wrong table name, the method is as follows:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception ex)
    {

        /*return new ModelAndView("error", "errMsg", ex);*/
        return "error";
        /*System.out.println(ex);*/

    }
```

The problem is that the method does not redirect me to my error.jsp when I return "error" or a ModelAndView, instead

```
 Feb 17, 2014 3:47:10 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
    Feb 17, 2014 3:47:10 PM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
    INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
```

is printed. When I try printing the error, it shows the

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
```

as it should. 
Do I need to add anything to my application-servlet.xml
Please explain this behaviour. Thanks

Comment: post your dao method, your controller method for more info

Comment: They are both very big and not to be posted, what I am looking for is the reason my method catches the exception to print it, but can't get the view resolved.

Comment: at least you should post your config for the view rendering in spring context.. this exception is not the problem

Comment: Those 4 lines in the logs don't seem to have anything to do with your `@ExceptionHandler`. If your handler doesn't show you error.jsp, what do you see in your response?

Comment: If I am using the return statements, nothing happens.